# How to create a URL condition with PHP for Menu Highligting?

Tags: php, url

For example I have a menu item named Categories and under that I have 10 different sub categories. So the url currently would be something like this:

```
http://domain/categories
http://domain/categories/sub1
http://domain/categories/sub2
...etc
```

I want to do something if the url is on categories regardless of what sub categories it is in.
So instead of typing out each sub categories sub1, sub2...sub10..etc.  How can I tell PHP to check if the URL is `http://domain/categories/` and all sub after this...almost like an "ALL" wildcard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple (primitive) approach is:

```
if(substr_count($actual_url, 'http://domain/categories'))
{
    //do whatever you like
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a boatload of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
$a = strpos($var1, $var2)
if($a !== false) { ... }
```